Optimizacion de Array
Note que el rendimiento de mi código no es óptimo cuando uso bucles y funciones para manipular estos arrays. ¿Qué recomiendan para mejorar la eficiencia y el tiempo de ejecución al trabajar con arrays de este tipo? Agradecería ejemplos de código que puedan mejorar esto.
function procesarArray(array) {
  let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      resultado.push(array[i] * 2);
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

const miArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 /* ... */, , 10000];
const resultadoFinal = procesarArray(miArray);
console.log(resultadoFinal);


Lo primero es evaluar cuanto demora tu algoritmo, para esto usamos la API de Performance


function createArray(n) {
  let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    resultado.push(n);
  }
  return resultado;
}

function procesarArray(array) {
 let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      resultado.push(array[i] * 2);
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

const miArray =createArray(1_000_000);

const t0 = performance.now();
const resultadoFinal = procesarArray(miArray);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms`);



Yo he probado con un millon de datos y de media me da 12ms
Consideraciones:

Para evaluar el tiempo se debe probar varias veces, no basta con el primer resultado obtenido
El resultado nominal variará entre computadores, lo relevante es encontrar una diferencia significativa entre cada algoritmo

1.- for vs for of
Recorrer un array con un índice haciendo for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++), es siempre más rápido que hacer usando iteradores for(var item of array). A mi la última forma me parece más comoda y la uso cuando la eficiencia no interesa.
En tu caso ya lo tienes con un for con índice
2.- Uso de funciones nativas
Muchas veces el uso de funciones nativas da un código más corto, lo cual también puede ayudar a la legibilidad (no siempre es cierto). Además, estas funciones vienen optimizadas por lo que siempre dan una buena performance, en tu caso puedes usar un map
array.map(a=> a % 2 === 0 ? a * 2: a)

A mí me da una media de 10ms


function createArray(n) {
  let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    resultado.push(n);
  }
  return resultado;
}

function procesarArray(array) {
 return array.map(a=> a % 2 === 0 ? a*2:a)
}

const miArray =createArray(1_000_000);

const t0 = performance.now();
const resultadoFinal = procesarArray(miArray);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms`);



3.- Agregar vs Reasignar
Agregar un elemento a un array es más lento que reasignar un valor. En tu caso el array resultante tiene la misma dimensión que el original, por lo que es posible crear un array con dimensión (let resultado = Array(array.length)) el cual seteará todos los valores como undefined y luego cambiamos dichos valores


function createArray(n) {
  let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    resultado.push(n);
  }
  return resultado;
}

function procesarArray(array) {
  let resultado = Array(array.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      resultado[i] = array[i] * 2;
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

const miArray =createArray(1_000_000);

const t0 = performance.now();
const resultadoFinal = procesarArray(miArray);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms`);



Me da una media de 5ms
4.- Mutable vs Inmutable
En general trabajar con inmutabilidad tiene peor rendimiento (en memoria y rapidez) que trabajar con mutabilidad. En tu caso, estas creando un nuevo array manteniendo el original sin cambios (inmutabilidad). Si decides cambiar el array original obtendrás un mejor rendimiento


function createArray(n) {
  let resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    resultado.push(n);
  }
  return resultado;
}

function procesarArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      array[i] = array[i] * 2;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

const miArray =createArray(1_000_000);

const t0 = performance.now();
const resultadoFinal = procesarArray(miArray);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`${t1 - t0} ms`);



Me da una media de 1.6ms
Resultados:



Forma
Tiempo (ms)




Original
12


map
10


Reasignado
5


Mutable
1.6



